# How to play/pause a continuous activity on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I made an application where I can choose the interval of time, in seconds, of how often the web-service is called from the device.

By default this value is 5 seconds. The user needs to fill in a form in order to invoke the web-service successfully.

So, until now, I enter the application and the web-service is called immediately (actually after 5 seconds).

How can I make a play/pause button to give some time to the user to fill the data or maybe change the data later?

My code looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        if (location==null) {

            return;
        }

        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((currTime - lastTime) < intervalTimeMilli){

            return;
        }       

        if (lati!=location.getLatitude() || longi!=location.getLongitude()) {
            lati=location.getLatitude();
            longi=location.getLongitude();
        }

        try {

            lati = location.getLatitude();
            longi = location.getLongitude();

            webservice(lati, longi);

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A submit button. If user clicks on submit button, then only make a call to this webservice. Again enable the button only if required inputs have been filled.
2. Assuming you do not want the submit button to be shown. Make a check before the webservice call for required fields. If check passes, call the service otherwise do-nothing i.e. stay on same page and allow user to fill details.
3. To delay the webservice call, use Handler.postDelayed()

Comment: Should I use a togglebutton? Exactly what I have to do with the button? What method should it call?